# Expland dataframe with lists inside observations in R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

This might have been asked before but I can't find a concrete answer.
I have a dataframe (df), that after some data manipulation looks something like this:

[image: dataframe1]

I would like to expand this dataframe, in order to get matched values.
The ideal output would look like:

[image]

Being value1.1, value1.2, value1.3, whatever is in the <dbl [3]> contained in the initial dataframe.

Sorry for not giving a reproducible example, my data has dozens of variables ther than test1 & test2 and I have to successfully unpack them all.

Comment: You may take a look at `tidyr::unnest` (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unnest.html)

Comment: @iago Thanks, this is what I was looking for however I could not remember the name of the function. Works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I just used unnest...

df %>% unnest(-Obs)